# Is there a basic hands-on example of the use of UK GIS data (not in the ESRI native format) being imported for use in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, data, united-kingdom

Is there a good, free, generally available hands-on UK-based example of UK GIS data (not in the ESRI native format) being imported for use in **ArcMap**, using ESRI tools only?

I want to find and organize GIS data to create a map that **ArcGIS Desktop** can consume.  The example would need to furnish some data and maps, rather than assuming that I already have something suitable.

I am not looking for a solution to a programming problem; I am hoping to demonstrate that ArcMap can work with, for example, OS data.

Comment: are you wanting a programming solution? If just gui interface try looking at the esri channel and looking for catalog search

Comment: I have clarified the question (hopefully).

Comment: I will try to provide an example: UK police has an online data center through which you can download crime data for given months. Data is in .CSV format, and includes Longitude and Latitude fields, using which you can upload the data to ArcMap and create a point layer of crimes. This will be done using File > Add Data > Add XY Data. The data is found here: data.police.uk/data You can combine this point data with polygon layers or a basemap and create interesting maps. The Office for National Statistics provides polygon layers of places such as the London Metropolitan Area.

Comment: Your editing so far seems to have been fairly superficial that means, at least to me, that this question remains very broad.  To focus your question into something suitable perhaps you can ask "How can ArcMap display Ordnance Survey data?", and include details of what your research has uncovered so far.  That will show what you have tried and precisely where you are stuck.

Comment: This question has become more confusing; What data format do you want to support? OS supplies some data in Shapefile format (https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html) Which ArcGIS supports natively. I'll suggest that you narrow the question, and tell us which data format you want to work with.

Comment: OK by "worked" you mean hands-on (step by step)? To make the question salvageable (less open ended so someone can actually answer), Choose one specific format, name a source for that format and give a few example feature types/classes you want to work with. There are simply too many options. petroleum prod, transport networks, utility systems, demographics, land use; on and on...

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe and Brad and PolyGeo thank you for your comments. As strange as it might seem, I'm interested in the general process of using non-ESRI data formats, rather than a specific format. The answer from Nir in the comments would be fine from my point of view if it could be fleshed out a bit as an answer. I take your points about the question being too broad with regards for the terms-of-reference of this site - but on the other hand it was the question I wanted to ask!

Comment: I figuered as much, would be happy to post it as an answer but it's impossible at the moment since your question has been put on hold. Maybe an admin could help.

Comment: Is it possible that your question is simply about "How to use GML 3 data in ArcMap?"  Something I am struggling with is trying to understand the black and white distinction you seem to be making between "ESRI native format" and "not in the ESRI native format".  The core ArcGIS for Desktop product can direct read (and often write) many formats that I would consider "non-native", and many more using its Data Interoperability extension.  If you could tell us even one format that you have or anticipate difficulty with then your question becomes much more likely to be re-opened.

Comment: It seems that EleventhDoctor simply wanted an example of Arc's ability to import and handle a non-native format. It is an unusual request for the reason PolyGeo and others mentioned (very broad), and thus the respondents are struggling with the "Why" of it, yet it's pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

ESRI provide a number of free "Getting started" online courses.  This will be a good starting point for you.  I would start with [this](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.webCourseDetail&courseid=2500) course as it introduces the basics of GIS and ArcMap.

All the other free online courses ESRI provide can be found [here](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=search.results&cannedsearch=2).

Answer (score 2):

Confused now by the question and responses.

Perhaps you are wanting to:

- Learn how to search for data;
- Use data in the desktop program; and/or
- Learn GIS

Esri has a jungle of available resources. Here are a few:

- [youtube.esri](https://www.youtube.com/user/esritv)
- [esri channel](http://video.esri.com/channel/0/latest)
- [ArcNews, ArcUser, ArcWatch](http://www.esri.com/esri-news)
- [Training, Virtual Training](http://www.esri.com/training/main/my-training)